# Second-order perturbation in Brans-Dicke gravity

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, perturbation-theory, variational-calculus, modified-gravity

Let be  $g_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$ the perturbation of the metric and   $\phi=\phi_0 + \varphi$ the perturbation of a field.
The lagrangian of a scalar-tensor theory of gravity is:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\mathcal{L} = \sqrt{-g} R \phi - w \sqrt{-g} g^{\alpha \beta } \dfrac{\nabla_{\alpha}\phi \nabla_{\beta}\phi}{\phi}
\end{equation}

I want to  compute this lagrangian at the second order perturbation,  $\mathcal{L}^{(2)}$. My attempt was:

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\mathcal{L}^{(2)} = (\sqrt{-g} R)^{(2)} \phi_0 - w \dfrac{\nabla_{\alpha} \varphi \nabla^{\alpha} \varphi } {\phi_0}
\end{equation}
**Is this correct?**
It seems correct to me but  leads me to a different result from my book. ___________________________________________________________________

What does " second-order " mean for a Lagrangian that depends on **two** fields ($g_{\mu\nu}$ and $\phi$) ? We must also consider terms like $\partial h \partial \varphi$ (cross terms) or we take only perturbation terms $\partial h \partial h$ and  $\partial \varphi \partial \varphi$ ?

Comment: Note that the metric appears implicitly in $\nabla^{\alpha} \phi$

Comment: @Eletie I have taken that into account. My doubt is if the second term of (2) is the only way to have a second order term or if there are other possibilities.

Comment: No, 'second order' does not mean 'two' fields. It means that you perturb the Lagrangian (by perturbing one field, two fields, or whatever you're interested in) and write the perturbative expression up to 2 orders in an (book-keeping) expansion parameter.

Comment: @Avantgarde I know it. So, if $h$ and $\phi$ are the two perturbation fields, one in general have to consider also mixed terms $\partial h \partial \phi$ in the second order lagrangian or not ? This would imply that the expansion parameter for $h$ and $\phi$ is the same

Comment: Well, depends on what is the second order Lagrangian that you want to find: of the graviton, or the field, or both.